# Get CPU usage for a specific running PHP script

Tags: php, linux, shell, process, command

I'm running multiple PHP script asynchronously. I want to get count (and if it is possible CPU percentage usage) of all script running by PHP.
Now i'm using `ps -C php --no-headers | wc -l` that returns count of all php scripts but i want count of only a specific script. When I use htop i see full address and parameters but i can't specify parameters in `ps` command.
How can I do that?
**Edit #1:** My script that is running multiple times asynchronously has a common name with other scripts (cake.php (for CakePHP framework)). And i'm trying to get the script by an argument that is being sent to the script (cake.php my_arg). I want scripts with argument **my_arg**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-p PID` instead of `-C php`, but you need to check which PID is executing your php script.

Also I think that if you did `-C my_script.php` it should work (depends on how you run your scripts).

Comment: Thank you @krzyk. I don't know PID of process that is running. Because there are multiple processes running (about 100 processes). Also -C my_script.php did not work.